# Object is deallocated don't know why?

Tags: objective-c, ios

Please help me I am not able to understand why this is happening there a object  `_getProductType` is deallocate without any reason. please take a look, I am not able to figure out what is happening , if you can help me I will be very thank full to you, Thanks in advance

```
    //
    //  ProductComponentViewController.m
    //  TurfNutritionTool
    //
    //  Created by Aashish Joshi on 10/14/11.
    //  Copyright 2011 Abacus Consultancy Services. All rights reserved.
    //

    #import "ProductComponentViewController.h"
    #import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

    @implementation ProductComponentViewController

    @synthesize productTableView =      _productTableView;
    @synthesize productTypeSelector =   _productTypeSelector;
    @synthesize turftypePopover =       _turftypePopover;
    @synthesize gotTurftype =           _gotTurftype;
    @synthesize resultProduct =         _resultProduct;
    @synthesize productTableCellStyle = _productTableCellStyle;
    @synthesize dbObject =              _dbObject;
    @synthesize getProductType =        _getProductType;

    #define Granular @"G"
    #define Liquid @"L"
    #define Tankmix @"T"
    #define AllProduct @"A"

    - (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
       {
        self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
        if (self) {
            // Custom initialization
        }
        return self;
       }

         - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
         {
        // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
        [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

       // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
       }

    #pragma mark - View lifecycle

       - (void)viewDidLoad
       {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        // D    o any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

        UIColor *_background = [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"main_bg.png"]];
        self.view.backgroundColor = _background;
        [_background release];

        // init the segment button value 
        [productTypeSelector setSelectedSegmentIndex:0];

        _getProductType = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:AllProduct];

        // set table delegate
        _productTableView.delegate = self;

        // load the product
        [self loadProductComponentValues];

        // Set the table view to be rounded
        [[_productTableView layer] setCornerRadius:5.0];
    }

    - (void)viewDidUnload
    {
        [self setProductTableView:nil];
        [self setProductTypeSelector:nil];

        _productTableView = nil;
        _productTypeSelector = nil;
        _turftypePopover = nil;
        _gotTurftype = nil;
        _resultProduct = nil;
        _productTableCellStyle = nil;
        _getProductType = nil;

        [_getProductType release];
        [_productTableView release];
        [_productTypeSelector release];
        [_turftypePopover release];
        [_gotTurftype release];
        [_resultProduct release];
        [_productTableCellStyle release];

        [super viewDidUnload];
        // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
        // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
    }

    - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
    {
        // Return YES for supported orientations
        return YES;
    }

    - (void)dealloc {

        [_getProductType release];
        [_productTableView release];
        [_productTypeSelector release];
        [_turftypePopover release];
        [_gotTurftype release];
        [_resultProduct release];
        [_productTableCellStyle release];    

        [super dealloc];
    }

    #pragma mark - Table view data source

    - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
    {
        // #warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
        // Return the number of sections.
        return 1;
    }

    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
    {
        // #warning Incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of rows in the section.

    // NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);
    return [self.resultProduct count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {

        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"productContentTableCellStyle" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = _productTableCellStyle;
        self.productTableCellStyle = nil;
    }


    NSDictionary * _productRow = [_dbObject getProductdetail:[self.resultProduct objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];


    // Configure the cell...

    UILabel* _label = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
    NSString* _linkcode = [_productRow objectForKey:@"linkcode"];  
    _label.text = _linkcode;

    _label = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:2];
    NSString* _description = [_productRow objectForKey:@"description"];
    _label.text = _description;

    _label = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:3];
    NSString* _productcode = [_productRow objectForKey:@"productcode"];
    _label.text = _productcode;

    _label = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:4];
    NSString* _weight = [_productRow objectForKey:@"weight"];
    _label.text = _weight;

    _label = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:6];
     NSNumber* _costperBag = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithFloat:[[_dbObject getUserProductCost:[self.resultProduct objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]] floatValue]];
    _label.text = [@"$ " stringByAppendingString:[_costperBag stringValue]];
    [_costperBag autorelease];


    _getProductType = [_productRow objectForKey:@"producttype"];

    if ([_getProductType isEqualToString:@"G"]) {

        _label = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:10];
        NSString* _weightTag = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"Weight in Lbs"];  
        _label.text = _weightTag;
        [_weightTag autorelease];

        _label = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:11];
        NSString* _SGNTag = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"SGN"];  
        _label.text = _SGNTag;
        [_SGNTag autorelease];

        _label = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:5];
        NSString* _sgn = [_productRow objectForKey:@"sgn"];
        _label.text = _sgn;

} else if([_getProductType isEqualToString:@"L"]) {

        _label = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:10];
        NSString* _weightTag = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"Weight in Ozs"];  
        _label.text = _weightTag;
        [_weightTag autorelease];

        _label = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:11];
        NSString* _SGTag = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"SG"];
        _label.text = _SGTag;
        [_SGTag autorelease];


        _label = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:5];
        NSString* _sgn = [_productRow objectForKey:@"sg"];
        _label.text = _sgn;

    } else if([_getProductType isEqualToString:@"T"]) {

         _label = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:10];
         NSString* _weightTag = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"Weight in Ozs"];  
        _label.text = _weightTag;
        [_weightTag autorelease];

        _label = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:11];
         NSString* _SGTag = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"SG"];
        _label.text = _SGTag;
        [_SGTag autorelease];    

        _label = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:5];
        NSString* _sgn = [_productRow objectForKey:@"sg "];
        _label.text = _sgn;
    }
    return cell;
}

- (UIView *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section { 

    UIColor *_background = [[[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"toolbar_bkg.png"]] autorelease];
    UIView* _customView = [[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10.0, 0.0, 300.0, 44.0)]autorelease];
    _customView.backgroundColor = _background;
    return _customView; 
}

- (UIView *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section { 

    UIColor *_background = [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"toolbar_bkg.png"]];
    UIView* _customView = [[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10.0, 0.0, 300.0, 44.0)]autorelease];
    _customView.backgroundColor = _background;
    [_background release];
    return _customView ;    
}

#pragma mark - Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Navigation logic may go here. Create and push another view controller.
    /*
     <#DetailViewController#> *detailViewController = [[<#DetailViewController#> alloc] initWithNibName:@"<#Nib name#>" bundle:nil];
     // ...
     // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
     [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
     [detailViewController release];

    if (_delegate != nil) {
        NSString *_selectedTurftype = [_getTurftype objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [_delegate getSelectedTurftype:_selectedTurftype];
    }
     */
    // NSDictionary * _productRow = [_dbObject getProductdetail:[self.resultProduct objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    // Animate the deselection
    [self.productTableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:[self.productTableView indexPathForSelectedRow] animated:YES];

    CGRect _popoverRect = CGRectMake(800.0f, 380.0f, 10.0f, 10.0f);

    if ([_turftypePopover isPopoverVisible]) {
        [_turftypePopover dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
    }
    else
    {
        ProductDetailViewController* _productDetailViewControllerObj = [[ProductDetailViewController alloc] init];
        _turftypePopover = [[UIPopoverController alloc]
                            initWithContentViewController:_productDetailViewControllerObj];
        _productDetailViewControllerObj.dbObject = _dbObject;

        [_productDetailViewControllerObj getSelectedProductId:[self.resultProduct objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] ];
        [_productDetailViewControllerObj release];
        _turftypePopover.popoverContentSize = CGSizeMake(360, 500);
        [_turftypePopover presentPopoverFromRect:_popoverRect inView:self.view 
                        permittedArrowDirections:0 animated:YES];
    }

    [self.productTableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:[self.productTableView indexPathForSelectedRow] animated:YES];
}

#pragma mark - ProductComponentViewController lifecycle methods

- (IBAction)laodTurftype:(id)sender {

    [self initAllTheProduct];

    if (_getProductType == (id)[NSNull null] && _getProductType == nil) {

        _getProductType = [NSString stringWithString:AllProduct];
    }

    if ([_turftypePopover isPopoverVisible]) {
        [_turftypePopover dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
    }
    else
    {
        TurftypePopoverViewController* _turftypeControllerObj = [[TurftypePopoverViewController alloc] init];

        _turftypeControllerObj.dbObject = _dbObject;

        _turftypeControllerObj.delegate = self;

        _turftypePopover = [[UIPopoverController alloc]
                            initWithContentViewController:_turftypeControllerObj];
        [_turftypeControllerObj release];

        _turftypePopover.popoverContentSize = CGSizeMake(150, 225);
        [_turftypePopover presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:sender
                                 permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny
                                                 animated:YES];
    }
}

- (IBAction)setProductType:(id)sender {

     switch (_productTypeSelector.selectedSegmentIndex) {
         case 0:
             _getProductType =  [NSString stringWithString:AllProduct];
             break;
         case 1:
             _getProductType = [NSString stringWithString:Granular];
             break;   
         case 2:
             _getProductType = [NSString stringWithString:Liquid];
             break; 
         case 3:
             _getProductType = [NSString stringWithString:Tankmix];
             break; 
     }

    [self loadProductComponentValues];
    // Check Point
    [TestFlight passCheckpoint:@"SET_PRODUCT_TYPE"];
}

// This is Delgate Method to get selceted product
-(void) getSelectedTurftype:(NSString*) getTurftype {

    self.gotTurftype = getTurftype;
    NSLog(@"self.gotTurftype %@", self.gotTurftype);
    [self loadProductComponentValues];

    if ([_turftypePopover isPopoverVisible]) {
        [_turftypePopover dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
    }
}

-(void) initAllTheProduct {

    _getProductType = [NSString stringWithString:AllProduct];
    self.gotTurftype = nil;

    // init the segment button value 
    [productTypeSelector setSelectedSegmentIndex:0];
    [self loadProductComponentValues];
    // Check Point
    [TestFlight passCheckpoint:@"SET_ALL_PRODUCT"];
}

- (IBAction)setAllProduct:(id)sender {

    [self initAllTheProduct];
}

// This Method use for Load Value of ProductComponent
- (NSMutableArray*) loadProductComponentValues {

    [self.resultProduct removeAllObjects]; 
    if (!_dbObject) [self loadDBAccessDatabase];

    self.resultProduct = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[self.dbObject getRelatedProductArray:self.gotTurftype andProductType:_getProductType]];
    [_productTableView reloadData];
    return self.resultProduct;
}

- (NSMutableArray *) loadProductComponentValuesIfEmpty {
    // NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);

    [self initAllTheProduct];
    if (!_dbObject) [self loadDBAccessDatabase];
    if (!self.resultProduct || ![self.resultProduct count]) self.resultProduct = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[self.dbObject getRelatedProductArray:self.gotTurftype andProductType:_getProductType]];
    // Check Point
    [TestFlight passCheckpoint:@"LOAD_DATABASE"];

    return self.resultProduct;
}

- (DBAccess *) loadDBAccessDatabase {
    // NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);
    if (!_dbObject) {

        NSString * _dbFileName = @"turfnutritiontool.db";
        _dbObject = [[DBAccess alloc] initWithSSDBAccessFilename:_dbFileName];
    }
    return _dbObject;
}

@end
```

Comment: *_getProductType is deallocate without any reason*. Yes there is a reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use:
self._getProductType = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:AllProduct];

change this sequence:

```
    [_getProductType release];
    [_productTableView release];
    [_productTypeSelector release];
    [_turftypePopover release];
    [_gotTurftype release];
    [_resultProduct release];
    [_productTableCellStyle release];

   _productTableView = nil;
    _productTypeSelector = nil;
    _turftypePopover = nil;
    _gotTurftype = nil;
    _resultProduct = nil;
    _productTableCellStyle = nil;
    _getProductType = nil;
```

you were leaking memory as setting pointers to nil, //memory leak
first you should release then set pointers to nil;// no leak

Comment: self._getProductType = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:AllProduct]; is incorrect. In this case, you should use self._getProductType = [[[NSString alloc] initWithString:AllProduct] autorelease];, in other case you'll have memory leak.

Comment: Wrong, `self._getProductType` isn't the property name at all, it is synthesized as `getProductType = _getProductType;`. `_getProductType` is the ivar name, and therefore, it is not the problem here. I would bet on a line such as `_getProductType = [_productRow objectForKey:@"producttype"];`

Comment: I have not checked your complete code but doing these few things should work for u.

Comment: Or better yet, don't set ivars to `nil` in `dealloc` at all.

Comment: I am so thank full to all you, I got better understanding of writing good code. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

Prefer using property accessors to directly accessing instance variables in methods other than `init...` and `dealloc`. For example, there are a number of places where your code is currently doing things like this:

```
 _getProductType =  [NSString stringWithString:AllProduct];
```

Leaving aside that `getProductType` is a silly name for a property (which goes double for the instance variable, not to mention that the synthesized setter method name would be `setGetProductType`), this code directly assigns an object to an instance variable without taking ownership of the object. Don't do this. Instead, do one of the following:

```
// First let's rename your property. In the .h file, modify the current declaration like so:
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *productType;

// In the .m file, change the @synthesize statement:
@synthesize productType = _productType;

// In cleaning up any compiler errors/warnings from references to the old names,
// modify code that directly assigns to the instance variable (other than in `dealloc`):

// So change this:
_getProductType =  [NSString stringWithString:AllProduct];

// to the following:
self.productType = [NSString stringWithString:AllProduct];

// ...or better yet:
self.productType = AllProduct;

// Note that the above statement is equivalent to the following:
[self setProductType:AllProduct];
```

#### EDIT

Also as @samfisher correctly points out, don't set ivars to `nil` *before* sending them `release` messages in `dealloc`.

Comment: I am so thank full to all you, I got better understanding of writing good code. Thanks a lot

Answer (score -2):

When **_getProductType** is allocated on this line

```
_getProductType = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:AllProduct];
```

it is not retained in any way.

and as soon as _getProductType goes out of scope (which is after **viewDidLoad** finishes) you will not be able to reference a valid object.

so every time you reference _getProductType outside of viewDidLoad it will be as if 'released'.

Your dealloc method releases it correctly so all you have to do is add a 'retain' after allocation/initialisation, thus:

```
_getProductType = [[[NSString alloc] initWithString:AllProduct] retain];
```

However, it might be a really good idea to study properties and how they work, how they can be set up to do things like retaining or copying data as and when it is initialised. Your starting point is [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html).

Comment: No need to retain anything in this line. *it might be a really good idea to study properties and how they work*, good advice. Solving an app crash by over retaining objects isn't a good solution

Comment: okay - lets see those @property declarations then, is there a retain present (or equivalent for those of you strong/weak)

Comment: I am so thank full to all you, I got better understanding of writing good code. Thanks a lot

Comment: I found one more thing that i use one selector method with wrong name which causing some problem but i found the solution by all of your help . Thanx :)